# How to disable sidebar on homepage?

Tags: layout

I am a newbie. I have 2 new site I have installed Magento 1.8. I have installed templates I bought from Template Monster. I have installed the demo home page html and demo home page xml. But the sidebar will not go away?

Both themes say they are "2 columns" but in Magento admin the layouts available are "2 column with right bar" or "2 column with left bar".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You need to look for something like this in one of the layout files (maybe page.xml, local.xml etc....... depending on you theme):

```
<reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

and change it to

```
<reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

for the **homepage**

The files would be located at

`\<your_magento_installation>\app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\`

**UPDATE:**

You could also simply go to your `admin panel`, in `CMS->Pages`, select your `homepage`, in `design` in `Layout update XML`, simply add the above code to set the layout to the 1 column layout.

Comment: **Important:** 1 more thing I forgot to mention if you're making changes to the files directly, don't change the base files. Follow the rules. Inherit(Copy) them in your theme and then make the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You should choose a single column layout, since 2 columns means main column + any side column.

You have 3 options from the CMS > yourPage > Design > Page Layout. Chose 1 column layout.